# How to use the MediaWiki API to search specifically for the number 0

Tags: wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

Is there a way to use the MediaWiki API to search articles for the number 0?

I've tried `api.php ? action=query & list=search & srsearch=0` and it returns:

```
"error": {
    "code": "srsearch-text-disabled",
    "info": "text search is disabled",
    "*": "See https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php for API usage"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That seems like a bug. You can add some ignored character to get around it:
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=.0

Comment: This does work but the extraneous character in this case may affect the results' index ranking. Compare [srsearch=1](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=1) and [srsearch=.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=.1)